# Rasa : Building a custom Action Server Image on GCP

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, rasa

I have some extra dependecies in my actions.py file of rasa chatbot. So i build a DockerFile using this link Deploying a Rasa Open Source Assistant in Docker Compose.

Everything went file like creating a image build and push.

Then i used this link Docker-Compose Quick Install.

but when i try to do sudo docker-compose up -d it returns following error:

```
Pulling app (athenassaurav/rasa:12345)… ERROR: pull access denied for athenassaurav/rasa, repository does not exist or may require ‘docker login’: denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

image : 
[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vr5X.png)

My Dockerfile is as follows :

```
# Extend the official Rasa SDK image
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:1.9.0

# Use subdirectory as working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy any additional custom requirements
COPY actions/requirements-actions.txt ./

# Change back to root user to install dependencies
USER root

# Install extra requirements for actions code, if necessary (otherwise comment this out)
RUN pip install -r requirements-actions.txt

# Copy actions folder to working directory
COPY ./actions /app/actions

# By best practices, don't run the code with root user
USER 1001
```

My docker-compose.override.yml look like this:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  app:
    image: <account_username>/<repository_name>:<custom_image_tag>
```

Comment: Could you be more clear in your question? Are you just trying to troubleshoot the one error?
If you are using Google Cloud Registry to pull the image, then the
image name needs to be specific as per the attached documentation
[1] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/
pushing-and-pulling#pulling_images_from_a_registry

Answer (score 0):

Your action server image is not on the same repo as the rest of the images you are pulling, so you need to do a `docker login` for your GCP repository. See options for authentication here https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication